# How to generate different deployables from the same Maven project?

Tags: maven-2

I have a situation that I'm sure must be fairly common. I have some Maven-built applications that deploy to different types of application server - like Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

The build processes 'tunes' the deployable artifact to the specific target type of application server (for example, different included dependencies, context roots, other config). This tuning is controlled with build profiles (-Ptomcat, -Pjboss etc)

So, for a given version of my application, I need to run builds that produce different deployables. I run `mvn -Ptomcat clean package` for example and I get an artifact in my /target directory that is the tomcat-tuned version.

The best approach I've been able to come up with so far is to specify finalnames for the artifacts that include the profile information, but for that approach, I'm not sure how to configure Maven to copy the final artifact off to some specific location so that the next build for a different type doesn't overwrite it.

Is this a good approach? If so, how can I achieve that final copy?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: Ah, thank you. In fact this example is explicitly mentioned, once I know what I'm looking for! http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html